# WCF Service configuration file, configure bindings with maxreceivemessagesize for clients to pull down?

Tags: wcf, service, configuration

Is it possible to use configurations on Bindings in my service config so that the client can pull them down automatically?? I noticed that things like below work fine.

```
<reliableSession enabled="true"/>
```

However, if I want to configure the binding with the following it doesn't pull down this section.

```
<binding name="MyBinding" maxReceivedMessageSize="2147483647">
    <reliableSession enabled="true"/>
</binding>
```

**Edit 1**

To be more clear, the client config receives

```
<binding name="NetTcpBinding_MyBinding">
    <reliableSession enabled="true" />
</binding>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No it is not intended to do this. It is about the size of messages 'received'. Essentially this element is intended to provide protection against denial-of-service attacks and therefore it's more about what protection you want, rather than some underlying parameter of the communication channel that both sides must agree on.

Comment: I see, I was just wondering if there was an easier way to setup my config without having to keep changing that parameter every time I update the config file with new info.